# Getting a 403 Forbidden message in a Django 4.2 POST request even after including the CSRF token

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to perform a language toggle feature in a website and I am using Django 4.2 and using Django's i18n library in the root level urls.py file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('',apiView.WebsiteHomepageTemplate.as_view(),name="url_homepage_template"),
)
```

In the template file , I am performing the language switch like this :

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="language-list">
                  <li class="" id="language-switcher">
                    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" name="lang_form">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
  
                      <select class="selectpicker" id="select_pickr" name="language">
                        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                        {% for language in languages %}
  
                        <option value="{{ language.code }}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected" 
                        {%endif %} data-content='{{ language.code }}}'>
                          {% if language.code == 'en' %}
                          English
                          {% else %}
                          हिंदी
                          {% endif %}
  
                        </option>
  
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                    </form>
                  </li>
                </ul>
```

**When I perform the toggle, I get a 403 forbidden message.**

[image: When I perform the toggle, I get a 403 forbidden message.]

**When I inspect using the dev tools I can see only 2 cookies being used , csrftoken & theme (for changing light and dark mode) till this moment**

[image]

So if I perform the toggle again while being on my custom 403 error page, I am able to toggle to the other language and upon inspection I can see the **lang** cookie is present.

When I do this from a private window the same thing keeps happening. It works after at least the 403 message is shown .

[image]

I can also see that the in the Request header my csrftoken is present.

On my server I am getting this message in the logs :
**Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /i18n/setlang/**

Some of my settings that I applied to make this site secure :

```
DEBUG = False
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',# for multi language 
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # ...caching
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',   
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # new   
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # ...caching
    # 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',      
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',  
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',  
    'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',    
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # AxesStandaloneBackend should be the first backend in the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list.
    'axes.backends.AxesStandaloneBackend',

    # Django ModelBackend is the default authentication backend.
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]



X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 86400
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.mywebsite.com']
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True






CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'","mywebsite.com","ajax.googleapis.com" )
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = (
    "'self'",
    "https://www.googletagmanager.com",
    "fonts.googleapis.com",
    "mywebsite.com",
    'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/',
    'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/embed/',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js',
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js",
    # "'strict-dynamic'"
    # "'unsafe-inline'"
)
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'", "fonts.googleapis.com","fonts.gstatic.com")    
CSP_STYLE_SRC = [
    "'self'",
    "mywebsite.com",
    "fonts.googleapis.com",
    "'unsafe-inline'"

]  
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'",'mywebsite.com','data:','blob:')
CSP_FRAME_SRC =(
    "'self'", 
    'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/', 
    'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/',
    "https://www.google.com/maps/"
) 
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://mywebsite.com" ,
]

#CONTENT SECURITY POLICY
CSP_CONNECT_SRC =("'self'","https://www.google-analytics.com/")
# CSP_OBJECT_SRC = ("'self'", 'mywebsite.com')
CSP_BASE_URI = ("'self'", )
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'","https://www.google.com/" )
CSP_FORM_ACTION = ("'self'", )
CSP_MANIFEST_SRC = ("'self'", )
CSP_WORKER_SRC = ("'self'", )
CSP_MEDIA_SRC = ("'self'", )
CSP_CHILD_SRC = ("'self'", )    
CSP_FORM_ACTION = ("'self'","mywebsite.com")
# CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'","mywebsite.com",)
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = [
    'default-src',
    'script-src',
    # 'style-src',
]
CSP_OBJECT_SRC = ("'self'","mywebsite.com")
```

Please help me in solving it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Add one line for url white listing **settings.py**

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://mywebsite.com"]
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked